# I Can't change my skin MCPE 0.15.0!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I try to change my skin the "Change new skin" sign isn't here anymore. This had happened on my phone and now my ipad. How can I get the sign back?

Answer (score 3):

You need to press the "coat hanger" icon on main menu. Here is image about the button: [image: main menu button]

Answer (score -1):

Click the coathanger and select the skin you would like